# XHTML: Why is my nested UL invalid?

Tags: html, css, validation, xhtml

The following menu works really fine in the browser, but I cant get it to validate as XHTML. I took this example out of my CSS Book. It says it is right, but seemingly it is not.

```
<ul id="leftNavi">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="SCL">left menu1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="SCNL">left menu2</li>
  <ul id="subnavi">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="inactive">menu2/1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="inactive">menu2/2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="inactive">menu2/3</a>
    <li>
  </ul>
  <li> 
    <a href="#" class="HCL">left menu3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here a link to the page: http://www.yiip.de/arbeit/testlayout/standard_template.html I am talking about the left menu.

Comment: Always try to indent everything correctly (see cletus' answer). Every space counts. Takes some time, but it saves you a lot of time in the end since you'll be able to spot little oversights way more easily.

Comment: No need to apologize. We don't bite here (I hope). :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<ul id="leftNavi">
  <li ><a href="#" class="SCL">left menu1</a></li>
  <li class="SCNL">left menu2
    <ul id="subnavi">
      <li><a href="#" class="inactive">menu2/1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="inactive">menu2/2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="inactive">menu2/3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="HCL">left menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

You had a couple of problems:

1. The line with 3 as the list item didn't have a correct closing `<li>` element; and
2. The `subnav1` list wasn't contained within a `<li>` element. It can't be a direct child of another list, which was the main problem with validating your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.
It seems to work now :)
I rly love this page, there is nothing better for a newbie when selfhtml cant help :)